# java- Issues while using custom adapter and layout for listview?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for this title but i must be specific as much as i can to get a good response. I have custom list view with custom adapter.
Here is my code for determining my items in the custom layout.

```
String[] listviewTitle = new String[]{
        "lstviewitem",   "lstviewitem", "lstviewitem", "lstviewitem",
        "lstviewitem",  "lstviewitem",  "lstviewitem",  "lstviewitem9",
        "lstviewitem","lstviewitem",  "lstviewitem", "lstviewitem"

};//12




int[] listviewbutton = new int[]{
        R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
        R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
        R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
};
```

So here is for the title and the button only, there are more but these that i want you to help me in it.
For putting them:

```
 List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
         hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
         hm.put("listview_discription", listviewShortDescription[i]);
         hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[i]));
         hm.put("listview_duration", listviewNumber[i]);
         hm.put("listviewrecornot",listviewrecornot[i]);
         hm.put("listviewbutton", Integer.toString(listviewbutton[i]));
                 aList.add(hm);
        }
    String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_discription", "listview_duration", "listviewrecornot", "listviewbutton"};
    int[] to = {R.id.listviewImage, R.id.title, R.id.locationlst, R.id.number, R.id.recornot, R.id.btnGO};

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_row, from, to);
    ListView androidListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_c);
    androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

So the title stops at lstviewitem9? i can't figure how although, it should work. I mean it shows only till lstviewitem9 and they are 12... Second thing the button, i use for it an right icon. I want to it to open another activity depending on the selected view, so i made this in list_row.xml

```
android:onClick="myClickHandler"
```

and in java:

```
     if (listview_c.getSelectedItem().equals("ListViewItem1"));
    startActivity(new Intent(customlistview.this, ListViewItem1.class));
}
```

and so on.. but i can't handle it.
Thanks

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` - You're only adding 8 items to `aList`, the 8th `String` in `listviewTitle` being `"lstviewitem9"`. The rest of your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Lol, didn't notice. Thanks anyway. Btw, i fixed the rest of my question

Comment: Hey, i made it for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) but when i open it it messages me with: This is app isn't responding?

Comment: Your arrays only have 12 items in them. Arrays are zero-based. The last index is 11, not 12. `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] listviewbutton = new int[]{
    R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
    R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
    R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right, R.drawable.ic_action_right,
```

};

There is an extra comma after last R.drawable.ic_action_right

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not adding 12 items to your adapter.

check what you're doing here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {}
```

by limiting your loop to 8 you won't get 12 items